# sql - Increment number over some specific record occurrences

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm using Amazon Redshift. I have a flag column containing either 0 or 1 based on a certain condition and everything sorted by ascending time, and I want a number (DesiredPartition) to increment whenever there's a 1 Flag. This is not possible with partitioning ofcourse.

```
| DesiredPartition | FlagValue | Time |
|------------------|-----------|------|
| 1                | 0         |      |
| 1                | 0         |      |
| 1                | 0         |      |
| 2                | 1         |      |
| 2                | 0         |      |
| 2                | 0         |      |
| 3                | 1         |      |
| 3                | 0         |      |
| 3                | 0         |      |
```

If I export all the data into a csv, and use a for loop in a programming language, then ofcourse it's very simple, but definitely not feasible. But I can't think of anything, and can't find anything with an sql query based approach.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: This should help https://medium.com/better-programming/4-ways-to-calculate-a-running-total-with-sql-986d0019185c

Comment: @jarlh I'm using Amazon Redshift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say which database engine you are using, so I'll assume it's a modern one that implements window functions.

Use `SUM()` as a window function, as in:

```
select *,
  sum(flagvalue) over(order by time) as desired_partition
from t
```

Comment: . . The question is tagged SQL.  Window functions have been part of the standard for a long, long time.  There is no reason to sound apologetic about using them.

Comment: On the other hand, an _optional extension_ to the ANSI/ISO SQL standard. (T611, "Elementary OLAP operations" here.)